# Работа с файловой системой JS ( Source->Filesystem )

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Я хочу, зайдя на определенный сайт, записывать в текстовый файл определенную информацию с помощью JS, тобеж просто вставить код скрипта в консоль прям на сайте,  и что бы запись шла в выделенную папку. Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать, саму папку я уже выделил.
[image: filesystem]

Comment: Браузеры не позволяют ничего записывать в файловой системе во имя безопасности.

Comment: Как я понял, позволяют. Иначе для чего тогда можно выделить папку для любого сайта или же для своего? Я видел как с ней по разному работают на своих сайтах, можно ли это делать на чужих...

Comment: В инструментах разработчика, может, и позволяют, а в скриптах — нет. Кроме того, на вашем скриншоте содержимое вашей локальной файловой системы, а не чужого сайта.

Comment: тогда вопрос, каким способом лучше передать текстовые данные или данные в формате json, на python?
если парсить сайт не получается.

Comment: Использовать в питоне selenium, например?

Comment: спасибо, посмотрю документацию по нему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делается это элементарно:

1. Пишешь на JS свой парсер
2. Добавляешь в парсер что-то вроде

```js
fetch('http://localhost:3000/', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({всякая: всячина})
})
```

3. Используешь свой парсер как [расширение](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions)
4. Создаешь маленький проект для [nodeJS](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/), с использованием:

   - [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express)
   - [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)
   - [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) - это на будущее
5. Запускаешь свой проект `node server.js` (*для этого можно положить на стол батник*)
6. `nodeJS File System` пишет все что надо в файлы, идешь спать

Все

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень сильно помогли !

Answer (score 0):

Работать с файловой системой через скрипт js, невозможно.

Comment: С файловой невозможно, но записывать данные в файл через js можно.